# Xampp mysql cannot access to any table

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi guys I am on windows server 2012 r2 fresh after a recovery of the ovh vps. We are using xampp mysql service as db but with no luck. I have tried to reinstall the whole xampp tried to delete the files ibdata1 ib_logfile0 ib_logfile1 but no luck the serve start correctly as soon as I try to create / read data from the phpmyadmin interface it stuck and crash. I have tried all my ideas and the attepts where fault so what I am begin to ask is Anyone have idea how to resolve?:) Thanks in advance.

```
2019-03-02 08:23:37 f40 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator. 
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.42-84.2 started; log sequence number 0
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3760 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 2620 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_slave_pos from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 2620 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1932: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
2019-03-02  8:23:37 3904 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.38-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:54 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__bookmark from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__navigationhiding from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
  2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
 2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:55 2848 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:56 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:56 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:56 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:56 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
2019-03-02  8:23:56 1164 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table phpmyadmin/pma__userconfig from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Comment: For the first message about ... innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  DELETE the line from your my.cnf or disable the line with a pound sign (shifted 3) and space character.  This message has the reference in the manual to help you resolve the problem, read the suggested information, please.
2019-03-02  8:23:37 2620 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table mysql/gtid_slave_pos from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. - 
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks we resolved by following a similar process thanks for the answer